# Dataflow streaming job not autoscaling up

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I created a Google Cloud Dataflow job using the following settings:

```bash
python -m main_worker \
    --streaming \
    --runner=DataflowRunner \
    --enable_streaming_engine \
    --setup_file=<project_root>/setup.py \
    --region=us-central1 \
    --project=<project_id> \
    --temp_location=<temp_bucket> \
    --machine_type=n1-standard-2 \
    --number_of_worker_harness_threads=2 \
    --experiments=use_sibling_sdk_workers \
    --sdk_container_image=<custom_worker_image> \
    --autoscaling_algorithm=THROUGHPUT_BASED \
    --max_num_workers=32
```

I then pushed enough elements to the input Pub/Sub topic to generate the following CPU usage and backlog for the pipeline:

[image]

The CPU usage is at or near 100% for over 15 minutes, and the max backlog peaks at about 11 minutes, and is over 5-ish minutes for at least 10 minutes as well. This looks like it easily exceeds the [documented autoscaling criteria](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/horizontal-autoscaling#streaming) of a backlog that lasts more than a few minutes and the average worker CPU usage threshold of 20%, yet the number of workers in the pipeline remained at 1 the entire time. I'd have expected autoscaling to trigger pretty quickly. Why is this pipeline not scaling?

**Some possible leads:**

I did see that there is some type of predictive autoscaling that involves a timer backlog of some kind when using streaming engine, as I am doing here. My pipeline is very simple and I didn't touch any sort of grouping/combine/windowing functionality in Beam, and the documentation is unclear if I need to do anything like that to enable this timer thing. Could that be the issue? Is there any documentation on how this works?

Also, I see that streaming pipelines are deployed with a fixed pool of Persistent Disks, equal in number to `--max_num_workers`. In my case, this should be 32 disks, but when I look under Resource Metrics at the "Current HDD PD" metric, it only says 30GB. The tooltip says this metric is "The current size of all HDD (standard) persistent disk resources associated with your job." Should this be higher, equaling 30GB x 32? Could that be restricting the scale up? If so, how do I allocate more disks?

If neither of the above, what could be happening to prevent autoscaling here?